# Why is GetManifestResourceStream() returning null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I have a simple console project where I'm trying to access a resource in the root directory of the project.

The namespace is `Names.Console` and the file I am trying to access is `Program.cs`

The code I have is:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
const string resourceName = "Names.Console.Program.cs"

var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName));

// more code
```

When I set a break after the stream declaration, `stream` is null but I can't figure out why?

I've been looking at several resources on how to do this such as: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/319292 & I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Select the file in Visual Studio, open up its Properties. What's the selected Build Action?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis it's set to `compile`

Comment: @VinylWarmth How do you expect it to be a resource, if its build action is set to compile?

Comment: That's the problem. When the Build Action is set to *Compile*, the file will be fed to the compiler as a source code file. What you want is to set the Build Action to *Embedded Resource*. But if you do that the file won't be compiled as C#, so you'll probably want to create two copies -- one as a source file, one as an embedded resource.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis thanks, care to do this is an answer & I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A project consists of many files and Visual Studio allows you to select what happens for each file through its *Build Action* property.

In your case, the `Program.cs` file has the *Build Action* set to *Compile*. This instructs the build system to feed the file to the C# compiler as a source file containing C# code.

Another possible *Build Action* is the *Embedded Resource* option. This instructs the build system to take any file (regardless of its contents) and embed it as a binary blob somewhere in the resulting assembly file(s). If you intend a file to be accessed using the `GetManifestResourceStream()` method, this is the *Build Action* that enables you to do it.

Now if you want your file to be *both* compiled as a source file *and* embedded as a resource in the assembly, I don't know if the build system offers any options to combine two options for a single file. As a workaround, you can create a copy of your file and set one of the copies to *Compile* and one of the copies as an *Embedded Resource*. Notice that it might be a good idea to find a way to automate the task of this duplication, otherwise you may end up with supposedly duplicated files that are actually out of sync.